# My spruce in top-heavy, why is it growing like this?

Tags: spruces

My white spruce has a lot of new growth on the top half of the tree, while on the bottom half there are only a few new branches, and they are really short (5x shorter than on the top). So the tree is getting very top heavy. This was the case last year as well.

I don't understand why it grows like this. Of course, the top half is exposed to more sunlight than the bottom half, but the bottom half should still receive enough light. All other spruces I see around here are conical, as they should be.

Why does my spruce have this weird shape? Is there anything I can do to encourage growth on the bottom half of the tree? A picture of the spruce is attached.

[image]

Comment: I'm not loving the tree-size to pot-size ratio, - could be the tree doesn't, either.

Answer (score 1):

You can prune twigs you don't want; BUT, wait until next spring and cut new candles ( new green twigs that have not yet developed needles).You can prune branches anytime but they will not grow again from the end/cut area. Apparently your tree has plenty of water and fertilizer for the vigorous upper growth. I grew 3 white spruce seedlings in my yard in zone 5 and they naturally made  uniform pyramid shapes with no  pruning.